# Checking for substring in DOS

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, masm

I have this code and I want to check if the second string is found in the first. If so, display "yes", otherwise "no", also the positions where it is found.

```
.model small
.stack 400h
.data

menu1 db "Introduceti primul sir:",0, '$'
menu2 db 13,10,"Introduceti al doilea sir:",0, '$'
buffer1 db 100, '$'
buffer2 db 100, '$'
contains_msg db "da",0
not_contains_msg db "nu",0

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  call clear_screen      
  call display_menu1    
  call read_string1
  call display_menu2
  call read_string2
  call comparing

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h
    
  

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4ch
  int  21h

;---------------------------------------------

display_menu1 proc
  mov  dx, offset menu1
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
display_menu1 endp

display_menu2 proc
  mov dx, offset menu2
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h
  ret
display_menu2 endp

clear_screen proc
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  al, 3
  int  10H
  ret
clear_screen endp

read_string1 proc
  mov dx, offset buffer1
  mov ah, 0Ah
  int 21h
  ret
read_string1 endp


read_string2 proc
  mov dx, offset buffer2
  mov ah, 0Ah
  int 21h
  ret
read_string2 endp

comparing proc
  MOV CX, offset buffer1 ;The size of the substring
  DEC CX
  MOV DX, offset buffer2; The size of the String
  LEA SI, buffer1       ; The String
  LEA DI, buffer2        ; The substring
  
FIND_FIRST:        
  MOV AL, [SI];   storing the ascii value of current character of mainstring 
  MOV AH, [DI];   storing the ascii value of current character of substring
  CMP AL,AH;      comparing both character
  JE FITTING;      if we find it we try to find the whole substring
  JNE NEXT
  
NEXT:
  INC SI; We go to the next char
  DEC DX; And the size of the string decreased
  JE N_FINDED
  JMP FIND_FIRST
FITTING:
  CLD
  PUSH CX ; I push this register because in the instruction REPE CMPSB
  PUSH SI ; They change.
  PUSH DI
  REPE CMPSB
  JNE N_FITTING
  JE FINDED
N_FITTING:
  POP DI
  POP SI
  POP CX
  JMP NEXT ; if the complete substring doesn't fit we go to the next char
FINDED:
  POP DI
  POP SI
  POP CX
  MOV AL, 0001H;  substring found
  JMP RETURN
  

N_FINDED:    
  MOV AL, 0000H;  substring not found
  
RETURN:
  ret 
comparing endp
end start
```

I was expecting at this point for it to at least show me "yes" or "no", but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: the code doesn't seems to be printing `contains_msg` or `not_contains_msg`. You need to print based on the comparing result.

Comment: Also, `MOV CX, offset buffer1 ;The size of the substring` won't work - it's the offset (address), not the size. You could calculate the size of buffer1 by doing `offset2 - offset1`, but what if the user inputs a shorter string?